# Getting an error when building a next project

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, build, nextjs-api-router

I have a nextjs project that I call a fake api like jsonplaceholder. everything is ok when I run dev and start it's build.

If i change the the api address to the wrong one in purpose, I get error and redirect me to the error page in development mode.

But when i try to build it i get an error that say :

Error occurred prerendering page "/". Read more: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/prerender-error
[fetch data function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nAFoT.png)

[call function to get data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6vFto.png)

[the error i get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/15C7U.png)

I want to build project without error even with wrong api address.
what should i do? I would appreciate it if you help me to solve this problem.

Comment: you can catch the error and decide action after that. if getPosts() ends up with errors you should catch it and process further... for example if api fails you can return empty array from catch function.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.